# Is the function $f: n \in N^{*} \longrightarrow |D(n)| \in N^{*}$ injective/surjective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Is the following function injective/surjective? $$f: n \in N^{*} \longrightarrow |D(n)| \in N^*$$

(where $D(n)$ is the set of all the divisors of $n$). My attempt:

1. It is NOT injective because $f(2) = f(3) = 2\ \ AND\ \ 2 \neq 3$
2. I believe this is surjective but I don't know how to prove it for every number in the codomain. Can you explain me how to do it?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Do you mean NOT injective?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument for (1) is correct. For (2), how many divisors does $2^n$ have?

Comment: Oh yes I didn't think about $2^n$. Is it correct if I write down in the exercise: f is surjective because $\forall b \in N^*, \exists 2^{b-1} \in N^* : f(2^{b-1}) = b$

Comment: I don't see where the $a$ comes in. And $f(2^n)=n+1$, right?

Comment: Yes, check now if it looks correct :)

Comment: Well, you want $2^{b-1}\in\mathbb{N}^*$, but that looks right.

Comment: Thank you @carmichael561, you've been really helpful to me. Have a great day!